# What is the correct approach to implement Card drag in Wpf?

Tags: wpf

I am currently developing a card game in WPF and using MVVM pattern to build connection between View and Model. The task would be to move a card by mouse click and hold. The cards are dynamically generated and populated in an `ItemsControl`. The main problem is that when a dragged card is moved to another card in player's hand and starts overlapping it goes under the non-moving card, which is an undesired behaviour. I want to the dragged card to be always on top. To my understanding for that I need to somehow take out the `FrameworkElement` of the dragged card from the `ItemsControl` so that it would be always on top. Moving a card on the UI is the View's task, so I want to implement this on the code behind. The `ItemsControl` got its elements through data binding using `ItemsSource`. This what I got so far:

```
    private void Card_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _originalPoint = e.GetPosition(MainDockPanel);
        Image card = (Image)sender;
        IList<Card> itemsSource = PlayerHandItemsControl.ItemsSource as IList<Card>;

        StackPanel PlayersHandStackpanel = FindVisualChild<StackPanel>(PlayerHandItemsControl);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsSource.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((PlayersHandStackpanel.Children[i] as ContentPresenter).Content != card.DataContext)
            {
                //Disabling HitTestVisible on other cards
                PlayersHandStackpanel.Children[i].IsHitTestVisible = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                //Somehow make the current dragged card be always on top
            }
        }
    }
```

And the view:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyHand" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCards}"
                          x:Name="PlayerHandItemsControl">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    x:Name="PlayersHandStackPanel"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Name, Converter={localconverters:NameToImageConverter}}" 
                               MouseLeftButtonDown="Card_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                               MouseMove="Image_MouseMove"
                               MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                               Height="{Binding ElementName=GameControlCodeBehind, Path=CurrentCardHeight}"
                               Width="{Binding ElementName=GameControlCodeBehind, Path=CurrentCardWidth}">
                        </Image>
                        

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>   
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

So the question would be how to properly implement a card drag behaviour taking into consideration that the dragged card need to be always on top compared to other elements in WPF?